# Div background-image not working with ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background-image

I know there are already a thousand questions about IE background-images bugs, but i've already followed all the advices and I still can't reach for a solution.

This style isn't rendering any background image on IE 7 and 8:

```
div#mainComponent {
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
z-index: 100001;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 10%;
color: @blue;
padding: 20px;
height: 424px;
overflow: auto;
width: 780px;
height: 320px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Since my purpose is to have a 0.8 opacity background, i've already tried with rgba, but nothing happened, now i'm having this simple solution but I still can't get it right.
I've removed all of the other properties, to see if it could be any compatibility issue, but still nothing works.

Can you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: You CSS code looks fine and working in IE's. Check whether image path `../images/bg.png` is correct.

Comment: Working link: http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/CPWhS/1/

Comment: Damn..So what can be giving me this hard-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try dragging the image itself into the browser. There could be something wrong with the image itself.

Here's a page that shows how to do rgba, including a fallback for IE: http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Here's the fallback for IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>

   <style type="text/css">

   .color-block { 
       background:transparent;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#50990000,endColorstr=#50990000); 
       zoom: 1;
    } 

  </style>

<![endif]-->
```